# Catel json deserialize

Tags: c#, json, serialization, catel

I try to serialize and deserialize a complex catel property to and from json.

But I need to serialize just the name of the object as string in json. Serialize is working perfect. I override the SerializeMember Method. And just get the Name from the object.

My Problem is the Deserialize. The DeserializeMember Method is not called for this member. Because it's a string in json and catel only deserialize Member which are matching with the concrete object.

Have someone an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to customize the GetSerializableMembers() and specify your custom member name there as well. Then the custom names should be handled by the serialization for you as well.

Comment: Hi. Don't understand. It's not a custom name. It's a complex property serialized as string. On deserialize the method for this member is not called.

Comment: Can you provide a repro?

Comment: No Problem, a colleague added a repro 8 month ago. https://catelproject.atlassian.net/browse/CTL-890 Because of no answer I added the question here.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll try to look into it when I have time, can't promise an ETA since I need to work on my actual work first.

Comment: Yes I understand. But the isue is open since 8 month. And I have no idea to solve this. If is a bug I can do a pull request. But maybe there is an other solution?